# Searching ASCII value in String Buffer

Tags: ascii, stringbuffer

In my below code I am searching the location of s value is "þ" which is called as a value marker in Oracle. The equivalent ASCII value of þ=254. How to search with respect to 254 instead of þ?

```
for(int i=1;i<=sb.length();i++){
  locationofs=sb.indexOf("þ",i);
    if(locationofs>0)
      {
        i=locationofs;
        sb.replace(i, i+1, "\""+"\n"+"\""+RECID+"\""+";"+"\""); 
      }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works fine for me:

```
String temp[] = sb.toString().split(""+(char) 254);

sb = new StringBuffer(SIZE);
for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    sb.append(temp[i]).append("\"\n\""+RECID+"\";\"");
}
```

I have also simplified your line:

```
"\""+"\n"+"\""+RECID+"\""+";"+"\""
"\"\n\""+RECID+"\";\""
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Sergi, It works but the loop is not executing forever. Whether we can search with respect to ASCII value in location of p ?

Comment: Why do you want a forever loop? Maybe I have not understood correctly. English is not my first language :p